# how to pass multiple values onchange event of <select> in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I want to show student from selected school, class and section. if I delete `'class_id' => $class_id, 'section_id' => $section_id,` from controller then it show all student from selected school otherwise it show nothing.  any solution please. where am wrong ?
This is file from where I have to select value

```
    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" >School<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                           <div class="col-sm-5">
                                               <select name="school_id" id="school_id" class="js-example-basic-multiple form-control" onchange="get_student_by_school_class_section_id()">
                                            <option value="" >Select School...</option>                                  
                                            <?php if (!empty($all_school_info)): foreach ($all_school_info as $v_school): ?>
                                                    <option value="<?php echo $v_school->school_id; ?>"
                                                    <?php if (!empty($all_student_complain_info->school_id)) {
                                                         echo $v_school->school_id == $all_student_complain_info->school_id ? 'selected ' : ''; } ?>>

                                                                <?php echo $v_school->school_name ; ?>
                                                    </option>
                                                    <?php
                                                endforeach;
                                            endif;
                                            ?> 
                                        </select>  
                                            </div>
                                            </div>      

                                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" >Class<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                           <div class="col-sm-5">
                                               <select name="class_id" id="class_id" class="js-example-basic-multiple form-control" onchange="get_student_by_school_class_section_id()">
                                            <option value="" >Select Class...</option>                                  
                                            <?php if (!empty($all_classes_info)): foreach ($all_classes_info as $v_class): ?>
                                                    <option value="<?php echo $v_class->class_id; ?>"
                                                    <?php if (!empty($all_student_complain_info->class_id)) {
                                                         echo $v_class->class_id == $all_student_complain_info->class_id ? 'selected ' : ''; } ?>>

                                                                <?php echo $v_class->classes_name ; ?>
                                                    </option>
                                                    <?php
                                                endforeach;
                                            endif;
                                            ?> 
                                        </select>  
                                            </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" >Section<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                           <div class="col-sm-5">
                                               <select name="section_id" id="section_id" class="js-example-basic-multiple form-control" onchange="get_student_by_school_class_section_id()">
                                            <option value="" >Select Section...</option>                                  
                                            <?php if (!empty($all_section_info)): foreach ($all_section_info as $v_section): ?>
                                                    <option value="<?php echo $v_section->section_id; ?>"
                                                    <?php if (!empty($all_student_complain_info->section_id)) {
                                                         echo $v_section->section_id == $all_student_complain_info->section_id ? 'selected ' : ''; } ?>>

                                                                <?php echo $v_section->section_name ; ?>
                                                    </option>
                                                    <?php
                                                endforeach;
                                            endif;
                                            ?> 
                                        </select>  
                                            </div>
                                            </div>
<div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" >Student<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                   <div class="col-sm-5">
                                       <select name="student_id" id="student" class="js-example-basic-multiple form-control" >
                                    <option value="" >Select Student...</option>                                  
                                    <?php if (!empty($student_info)): foreach ($student_info as $v_student): ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $v_student->student_id; ?>"
                                            <?php if (!empty($all_student_complain_info->student_id)) {
                                                 echo $v_student->student_id == $all_student_complain_info->student_id ? 'selected ' : ''; } ?>>

                                                        <?php echo $v_student->student_id.'&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$v_student->student_name.'&nbsp;('.$v_student->student_father_name.')' ; ?>
                                            </option>
                                            <?php
                                        endforeach;
                                    endif;
                                    ?> 
                                </select>  
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
```

This is ajax.php

```
function get_student_by_school_class_section_id() {
     var school_id = document.getElementById('school_id').value;
     var class_id = document.getElementById('class_id').value;
     var section_id = document.getElementById('section_id').value;
        var base_url = '<?= base_url() ?>';
        var strURL = base_url + "admin/global_controller/get_student_by_school_class_section_id/" + school_id + "/" + class_id + "/" + section_id;
        var req = getXMLHTTP();
        if (req) {
            req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (req.readyState == 4) {
                    // only if "OK"
                    if (req.status == 200) {
                        var result = req.responseText;

                        $("#student").html("<option value='' >Select Student...</option>");
                        $("#student").append(result);

                    } else {
                        alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                    }
                }
            }
            req.open("POST", strURL, true);
            req.send(null);
        }

    }
```

this is controller.php

```
public function get_student_by_school_class_section_id($school_id, $class_id, $section_id) {
        $HTML = NULL;
        $this->studentrecord_model->_table_name = 'tbl_studentrecords';
        $this->studentrecord_model->_order_by = 'student_id';
        $student_info = $this->studentrecord_model->get_by(array('school_id' => $school_id, 'class_id' => $class_id, 'section_id' => $section_id, 'status' => '1'), FALSE);
        if (!empty($student_info)) {
            foreach ($student_info as $v_student_info) {
                $HTML.="<option value='" . $v_student_info->student_id . "'>" .$v_student_info->student_id.'&nbsp;'.$v_student_info->student_name.'&nbsp;('.$v_student_info->student_father_name.')'. "</option>";
            }
        }
        echo $HTML;
    }
```

I want to show student from selected school, class and section. if I delete `'class_id' => $class_id, 'section_id' => $section_id,` from controller then it show all student from selected school otherwise it show nothing.  any solution please. where am wrong ?

Comment: Need more information.  Either we'll need more information about the `studentrecord_model->get_by` function, or, even better, we'll need more information about where the problem is actually occurring.  Try throwing `var_dump($class_id, $section_id);` into the controller function and check the response to see if the values are as expected.

Comment: `var strURL = base_url + "admin/global_controller/get_student_by_school_class_section_id/" + school_id + "/" + class_id + "/" + section_id;` is it correct

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that code as far as syntax goes.  That line will do what it says.  But without seeing a lot more of the code, I can't tell you whether what it says is what you want it to say.   

When you try running the page, is the ajax call correct?  Open the DevTools in your browser, take a look at the Network request, and try opening the pertinent request in a new tab.  Any error messages?

Comment: yeah ajax call correct problem is with global_controller.php I think because when I delete ` 'class_id' => $class_id, 'section_id' => $section_id,` from  `$student_info = $this->studentrecord_model->get_by(array('school_id' => $school_id, 'class_id' => $class_id, 'section_id' => $section_id, 'status' => '1'), FALSE);` then it show student from selected school but if add `'class_id' => $class_id, 'section_id' => $section_id,` because I want student list from selected school, class and section then it only show Select Student.... show no value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done by changing global_controller.php code like this

```
public function get_student_by_school_class_section_id($school_id, $class_id, $section_id) {
        $HTML = NULL;
        $school = $school_id;
        $class = $class_id;
        $section = $section_id;
        $this->studentrecord_model->_table_name = 'tbl_studentrecords';
        $this->studentrecord_model->_order_by = 'student_id';
        $student_info = $this->studentrecord_model->get_by(array('school_id' => $school, 'class_id' => $class, 'section_id' => $section, 'status' => '1'), FALSE);
        if (!empty($student_info)) {
            foreach ($student_info as $v_student_info) {
                $HTML.="<option value='" . $v_student_info->student_id . "'>" .$v_student_info->student_id.'&nbsp;'.$v_student_info->student_name.'&nbsp;('.$v_student_info->student_father_name.')'. "</option>";
            }
        }
        echo $HTML;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is studentrecord_model.php

```
public function all_student_record_info_by_scs($school_id, $class_id, $section_id) {
        $this->db->select('tbl_studentrecords.*', FALSE);
        $this->db->select('tbl_school.*', FALSE);
        $this->db->select('tbl_class.*', FALSE);
        $this->db->select('tbl_section.*', FALSE);
        $this->db->select('tbl_fee_department.*', FALSE);
        $this->db->from('tbl_studentrecords');
        $this->db->join('tbl_school', 'tbl_school.school_id = tbl_studentrecords.school_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('tbl_class', 'tbl_class.class_id = tbl_studentrecords.class_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('tbl_section', 'tbl_section.section_id = tbl_studentrecords.section_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('tbl_fee_department', 'tbl_fee_department.fee_department_id = tbl_studentrecords.fee_department_id', 'left');
        $this->db->where('tbl_studentrecords.school_id', $school_id);
        $this->db->where('tbl_studentrecords.class_id', $class_id);
        $this->db->where('tbl_studentrecords.section_id', $section_id);
        $query_result = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query_result->result();
        return $result;
    }
```